# Can I safely re-use a requests.Session with multiprocessing.Pool.map?

Tags: session, concurrency, python-requests, multiprocessing

I want to download many files from the same website. I want to do so by re-using a [`requests.Session`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=session#session-objects) object.

If I send multiple requests to the site concurrently with multiprocessing, can I re-use the same `Session` object?

e.g. is the following concurrency-safe? (thread-safe?)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import requests

s = requests.Session()

def download(url):
    return s.get(url).text

urls = ["https://example.com"] * 10

with Pool(5) as p:
    p.map(download, urls)
```